# insert objects from a list to table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of buttons and a table with 3 columns. I want to insert the values of the buttons in table columns with JQuery when the user clicks on a button. Is there any way for doing this with JQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var num;
   $('#selction li a').click(function() {
   num = $(this).text();
   $('tr > td').text(num);

 }); 
});
```

```css
#selction{list-style: none;}
#selction li {display: inline-block;}
#selction li a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer
}
.table-numbers {width: 100%;border-collapse: seprate;}
.table-numbers tr td {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-list">
    <ul id="selction">
        <li><a id="n1" data-id="n1" onclick="ButtonSelected('n1')" role="button">1</a></li>
        <li><a id="n2" data-id="n2" onclick="ButtonSelected('n2')" role="button">2</a></li>
        <li><a id="n3" data-id="n3" onclick="ButtonSelected('n3')" role="button">3</a></li>
        <li><a id="n4" data-id="n4" onclick="ButtonSelected('n4')" role="button">4</a></li>
                
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<table class="table-numbers">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I give you a tip? In the future put your code in jsfiddle so we can play with it. Also, I am not sure what you want. It sounds easy... but I don't really know what you want to do

Comment: look at my html i have a ul#selction that contains list of buttons.I want when user select a number ,this number be shown in table.for example when i click on 6 ,this number be put in row1 col1 ,and when select 2 row1 col2 from table be filled with number 2.Am i clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I suggest here is what you want to do... Since your question isn't really clear.

But I *suppose* that you want to add the text of a clicked link in the first empty cell of the table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
    
    $('#selction li a').click(function() {
        num = $(this).text();
        var emptyTDFound=false;
        $('td').each(function(){
            
            if($(this).text()=="" && !emptyTDFound){
                $(this).text(num);
                emptyTDFound=true;
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

```css
#selction{list-style: none;}
#selction li {display: inline-block;}
#selction li a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer
}
.table-numbers {width: 100%;border-collapse: seprate;}
.table-numbers tr td {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="number-list">
    <ul id="selction">
        <li><a id="n1" data-id="n1" role="button">1</a></li>
        <li><a id="n2" data-id="n2" role="button">2</a></li>
        <li><a id="n3" data-id="n3" role="button">3</a></li>
        <li><a id="n4" data-id="n4" role="button">4</a></li>
                
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<table class="table-numbers">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yesssss!exactlyit is what I want!thank you soooo much for your help